# Azure SDK to get scaleset metrics

Tags: azure, cloud, autoscaling, azure-vm-scale-set

I am trying to get metrics like Percentage CPU, Disk Usage for an azure virtual machine scaleset.

I have tried using the Rest Endpoints and it gives the desired metrics. Is there any SDK to get these values?

Rest Endpoint:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/xxx/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2019-07-01&metricnames=Percentage CPU&timespan=2020-12-30T03:00:00Z/2020-12-30T04:00:30Z

The above call requires a bearer token which is obtained from the oauth2/token call.

I want to make use of the SDK(if any) to get the metric definitions instead of developing a framework to get the metrics via a RestClient.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your programming language ?

Comment: Java. @StanleyGong